# Read DNG file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dng

I am trying to read dng files from iphoneX. 
I read the link https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/03/08/tips-for-reading-a-camera-raw-file-into-matlab/ 
But the error message is 'Reference to non-existent field 'SubIFDs'.'

```
info=imfinfo(dng_file_path);
info.SubIFDs{1} %where the error pop up
tiffHandle=Tiff((dng_file_path),'r');
offsets=TiffHandle.getTag('SubIFD');
setSubDirectory(TiffHandle,offsets(1));
CFA=double(read(TiffHandle));
```

Answer (score 0):

The DNG files from iphone seem to be compressed (lossless jpeg compression). Try running the file through DNG Converter with the preferences set to Uncompressed. Then try that in Matlab.